# DotPeek: cannot see compiler-generated code

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, dotpeek, jetbrains-hub

1. I have my library with one file that contains:

```
public class SomeClassWithAwait
{
    public async Task<int> MethodAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => 1 + 1);
    }
}
```

2. I turn on the feature "Show compiler-generated Code".
3. I see changes in "Assembly Explorer", for example - state machine for await. But I cannot see changes in the file. I see only async\await as before when I turn on feature from step 2.

What I tried: close\open file, close\open dotPeek, rebuild library in release\debug mode.

Version dotPeek: 2020.2.2 build on 2020-09-09 (latest for today).

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATED**

About "Use sources from symbol files when available" feature:
Still doesn't work for me, I got this:

```
public async Task<int> MethodAsync()
{
  int num = await Task.Run<int>((Func<int>) (() => 2));
  return num;
}
```

So, I still have async/await.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to see, exactly?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, the state machine for async/await

Comment: And why should the state machine be in your compiled code and not in the Microsoft .NET framework code?

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Use sources from symbol files when available". Then close the window with the code and reopen it.

[image: Use sources from symbol files]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work for me. Code changed but async\await is still here. Updated my question with details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the decompiled source:
Right click on a class -> Decompiled Sources

dotPeek will show the await/async state machine instead of the "async/await" statements.

[dotPeek Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JEdF.png)

See also the official documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Decompiled_Code.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).